# Comparar dos DataGridViews en C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

¡Hola Mundo!, tengo un pequeño detalle, desde un boton estoy comparando dos columnas de dos datagridviews. Lo que quiero obtener es: Del `DataDridView1` sacar todos los datos que no existen en `DataGridView2`. Lo que realmente hice es comparar los datos y los que son iguales pinte la fila del `DataGridView1`, hasta ahí todo bien.

Mi problema esque en el mismo `DataGridView1` tengo un checkbox en la primera columna (`Cells(0)`) y tengo que activar los checkbox para los datos que no coinciden. Segun yo si conciden desactivo el CheckBox y cuando NO, lo activan pero esa lógica no me funciona porque me deja todos activados.

Anexo codigo para ver donde estoy haciendo mal.

```
private void btnAdicionales_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    int intContador = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i <= this.DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        for (var j = 0; j <= this.DataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1; j++)
        {
            if (Trim(System.Convert.ToString(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value)) == Trim(System.Convert.ToString(DataGridView2.Rows(j).Cells(0).Value)))
            {
                DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Style.BackColor = Color.Coral;
                DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Style.BackColor = Color.Coral;
                DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Style.BackColor = Color.Coral;
                DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(4).Style.BackColor = Color.Coral;
                DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(5).Style.BackColor = Color.Coral;
                DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(7).Style.BackColor = Color.Coral;
                intContador += 1;

                DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = false;
            }
            else
                DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = true;
        }
    }
    int intDif = 0;
    intDif = intContador - System.Convert.ToInt32(DataGridView1.Rows.Count);
    ToolStripStatusLabel3.Text = "Adicionales: " + System.Convert.ToString(intDif);
}
```

Agradezco las sugerencias que me puedan dar.

Comment: El problema es que siempre estas comparando todo con todo, y no especificas en ningun momento que pare. Lo mejor que podes hacer es poner todo en falso al iniciar, y despues SOLO cambiar a verdadero los iguales.

Comment: Supongo que la primera celda debe ser algun Id?, tambien te recomiendo que especifiques en tu pregunta como esta implementado el Datasource de los gridviews, ya que  si son colecciones, es mucho mas sencillo sacar el diferencial usando linq directamente con los dataSources/ItemSource de ellos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que podrás hacer es un procedimento que active todos los checkBox que tengas en tu DataGridView,algo más o menos así:

```
public void activaChecks()
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DataGridView1.dgvExistencia.Rows){
        row.Cells(0).Value = true;
    }
}
```

ya en tu botón, instancias este procedimiento antes de hacer tus comparaciones y solo vas desactivando los checkBox que contenga los datos coincidentes, con eso ya no es necesario utilizar tu `ELSE`

También puedes ir **"rompiendo"** tu ciclo `for` para que no recorra todo el `DataGridView2`, si encuentra un dato coincidente, podrás salirte y continuar con el siguiente valor.

Tu código final podría quedarse algo así:

```
private void btnAdicionales_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    activaChecks();
    int intContador = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i <= this.DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        for (var j = 0; j <= this.DataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1; j++)
        {
            if (Trim(System.Convert.ToString(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value)) == Trim(System.Convert.ToString(DataGridView2.Rows(j).Cells(0).Value)))
            {
                DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Style.BackColor = Color.Coral;
                ...
                DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(7).Style.BackColor = Color.Coral;
                intContador += 1;
                DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = false;
                break; // romper el ciclo.'
            }
        }
    }
    ....
}
```